# Angular,основы Как это работает?

Tags: angularjs, angular2

Читаю книгу "Angular для профессионалов", только начал осваивать. И не могу понять, как это работает. 
Есть вот такой код:

```
  import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import { Product } from "./product.model";
    import { StaticDataSource } from "./static.datasource";
    @Injectable()
    export class ProductRepository {
     private products: Product[] = [];
     private categories: string[] = [];
     constructor(private dataSource: StaticDataSource) {
     dataSource.getProducts().subscribe(data => {
     this.products = data;
     this.categories = data.map(p => p.category)
     .filter((c, index, array) => array.indexOf(c) == index).sort();
     });
     }
     getProducts(category: string = null): Product[] {
     return this.products
     .filter(p => category == null || category == p.category);
     }
     getProduct(id: number): Product {
     return this.products.find(p => p.id == id);
     }
     getCategories(): string[] {
     return this.categories;
     }
    }
```

В конструкторе указан параметр,в котором говорится, что на вход конструктору должен прийти экземпляр типа StaticDatasource. У которого есть метод getProducts(). Его код в данной ситуации не особо важен.
Меня интересует, каким образом туда попадают данные, ведь нет никакой явной инициализации переменной типа StaticDatasource. Откуда он её берёт? Ведь аннотация в конструкторе просто указывает, что в конструктор должен быть передан объект такого-то типа, или я что-то не правильно понял? Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это называеться Dependency Injection. Angular сам все делает. Вот могу скинуть видео об этом простыми словами https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCok3uXqyk8&t=214s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание, на то, что вы скорее всего зарегистрировали StaticDatasource в модуле вашего компонента. Там и происходит инициализация - в провайдерах. Когда инициализируется ваш компонент, DI смотрит на тип зависимости из конструктора, и внедряет из ранее зарегистрированного массива провайдеров. В этом вся соль. Вам самим ненадо заботится каким образом внедрить экземпляр зависимости. Плюс, сервис объявленный в модуле, является синглтоном для всех компонентов этого модуля. (На самом деле не только для этих компонентов, но и для дочерних со стороны модуля, но это уже другая история)